# Problem with bringing textures from Substance Painter to Blender

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor

As I brought this material over to blender and hooked everything up, I noticed that some things where off.

This is how it looked like in substance painter(how it should look like):

[image]

And this is how it looked like in blender cycels:
[image]

As you can see its to reflective and the x on the side isn't even straight.

This is how my node setup looks like:
[image]

Ignore the displacement, it doesn't do anything here.

Some of my guesses are hdri, maybe cycels is different to the render engine in substance, I exported something incorrectly.

Comment: Your Normal Map, Roughness, Metallic and DIsplacement  textures should all have their _Color-Spaces_ set to _Non-Color_ (instead of sRGB)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that directly after posting this but the result is still the same

Comment: In that case, I know Substance uses DirectX by default for it's materials (though it can do both) and blender uses OpenGL. Make sure you have Substance set to create OpenGL maps (though there is a node based conversion if you're really stuck). Also, Substance has been known to export rather "strong" Normal Maps from time to time; If all else fails, try turning down the Normal Map strength.

Comment: maybe it's because of the light or environment.
Try it by bringing light closer perhaps

Comment: yup, I'm using open gl albedo map